# Output of True and []

Tags: python, syntactic-sugar

I was wondering why
`True and []`
returns [] instead of False

Is the expression a syntactic sugar ?

Comment: very good question, I never knew. I already have plans of this applicability in some aspects of my code where the True situaion would have needed to return an empty list. You see if the line is False and [], it returns false. nice..:)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer is found at [5.10. Boolean Expressions](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates *x*; if *x* is false, its value is returned; otherwise, *y* is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

Answer (score 2):

This syntactic sugar is sometimes used as a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) in Python

```
C++: someVar = someCondition ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse;
Python: someVar = someCondition and valueIfTrue or valueIfFalse
```

**Edit:** It turns out, as per comments :), this is a major pitfall in Python and should be replaced by

```
someVar = valueIfTrue if condition else valueIfFalse
```

Comment: Please note that these are not equivalent, there's a gotcha in the python version: If `valueIfTrue` evaluates to `False`, `valueIfFalse` will be returned whether `someCondition` is `True` or `False`. Use `someVar = valueIfTrue if someCondition else valueIfFalse` instead to avoid this pitfall.

Comment: Doesn't work if `valueIfTrue` evaluates to a False value. Then it is better to use `valueIfTrue if someCondition else valueIfFalse` (since 2.5). BTW: The `? :` originally comes from C, not from C++.

Comment: 1. It's not syntactic sugar. It's just... syntax. (otherwise: what is it sugar FOR?). 2. `a and b or c` in Python is WRONG. It might evaluate `c` when you didn't mean it to.

Comment: You can avoid the pitfall by exploiting the property of non-empty lists to eval to True: `someVar = (someCondition and [valueIfTrue] or [valueIfFalse])[0]` Even if valueIfTrue evals to False it will correctly be returned.

Comment: Sweet, I was looking for a ternary operator in Python! The only thing I have found so far was `[ValueIfFalse, ValueIfTrue][someCondition]` which is of course horrible in every way.